# SQL Server 2000 Live data mirroring

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000, mirror

I am currently working with 2 sql 2000 servers one I can query but not add any databases to which lead to the second one having lots of queries that use the first as a linked server. I would like to improve performance while still querying live data.

Is it possible to mirror the live data to the second server, that way the queries would be local to that server? What are my options?

If an upgrade from sql 2000 is needed that is a possibility.

The data has low update, insert, delete use and high select use so I think this would be ideal if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

1. use replication to move the data from the first server to the second.  This has the drawback of making changes extremely difficult due to the need to tear down and set the replication up for each change.
2. Use log shipping in SQL 2000.  The idea is that immediately after changes occur on your primary server, data is transferred to your standby server.  I haven't done this so I dont personally know the drawbacks.  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2000/maintain/logship1.mspx
3. Upgrade to SQL 2005 or SQL 2008 and use the built in mirroring features of it.  Be aware that you should do some fairly in depth testing to make sure everything works correctly after a major upgrade like this.  Although compatible I have had to make tweaks to certain application queries after an upgrade to keep everything functioning normally.

Comment: Think I will go with an upgrade