# How to connect to SQL Server redundantly using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-connection, redundancy

I have two SQL Server machines, `server1` and `server2` that are redundant and have the same data.

My application wants to select data from a table in the `msdb` database every 1 second. But my application can connect only using one conection string. How to edit my application can work redudantly with both servers?

- SQL Server 2000 SP4
- Window Server 2003
- C#

My connection string is

```
server=10.15.13.70;database=msdb;user id=sa;pwd=""
```

Please advise me.

Comment: Check out [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server) - but I'm afraid with a legacy system like SQL Server 2000 (no longer supported by MS), you'll be out of luck doing this automatically. You need to have two connection strings in your app - one for server1, another for server2 - and do the logic of connecting to one or the other server in your application code....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182101/sql-server-2000-live-data-mirroring

Comment: Frequently asked questions - SQL Server 2000 - failover clustering 
: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260758

Comment: Deleted "Failover Partner" answer; @marc_s correctly notes that this doesn't apply to SQL Server 2000

Comment: But here's a thought... it is 2011; you are several versions behind... maybe time to upgrade?

Comment: i can't upgrade because my boss's order may be in my factory run all time and difficult to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a server at random and insert the name or IP for that in the connection string before opening the connection.

```
using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=" + giveMeAServer() + ";database=msdb;user id=sa;pwd="))
```

and:

```
private String giveMeAServer()
{
    return "10.15.13.70";
}
```

The *proper* fix, especially if you are reconnecting as often as once per second, is most likely to set up some sort of cluster on the SQL Server side, and connect to that, rather than having your application worry about load balancing the database backend.

Answer (score 1):

Better is you try to open the connection for some interval say 5ms, and if connection cant be opened, switch to other server through connection string

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Load balancing`. This is a technique that can only be applied to readonly databases. It basically spreads the load across multiple servers.

Here is a good read on load balancing with SQL Server 2000 by Microsoft.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917707.aspx

Imho, what you try to achieve should not be handled programmatically but on a hardware level.

Answer (score -1):

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Failover Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;
```

(from http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1289)

Comment: Does that exist in SQL Server **2000** already?? I believe this is a new feature in 2005...